# How can I make an inner DIV fill to the height of an outer DIV when using display: table?

Tags: html, css

I have the following HTML which can be seen in this [fiddle:](http://jsfiddle.net/9DDgD/)

```
<div id="parent">
    <div id="a" class="grid_6" style="background-color: #ff00ff">
        <div class="block-border">
            <div style="background-color: #123456">
            Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="b" class="grid_6" style="background-color: #ffff00">
        <div class="block-border">
            <div id="xx" style="background-color: red;">
            Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

How can I make it so that the DIV with id="xx" expands in height to fill the containing DIV?

Comment: According to this jsFiddle, there are no problems!  http://jsfiddle.net/persianturtle/SLyTj/  You must have something being overridden.

Answer (score -1):

If you set the `.grid_6` to have `position: relative` and `#xx` to have `height: 100%; position: absolute;` it should work. Although, this may not be ideal.

```
#parent {
    display: table-row; 
}

.grid_6 {
    position: relative;
    display: table-cell;
    width: 50%;       
}

#xx {
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute; 
}
```

See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/derekaug/a8mpt/) as a working example.